# NetBeans lag spickes

Tags: netbeans, lag

I have a problem with my NetBeans. I have asked this question over at NetBeans forum but no one came with an answer. My problem is that everytime I hit enter after writing a bit of code, for example, System.out.println(); and then everything freezes for a second.

This happens all the time. This lag spike/freeze also happens when I write a DOT(.) after something like System.(DOT) then it freezes for a second. This makes NetBeans unusable. I'm running the latest Java at 64-bit and the latest JDK. I have reinstalled the program 2 times and nothing helps. Any idés?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like the *intelli sense* feature went wilde...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle any idé how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not a netbeans guy. I would be left to simply delete the project and personal configurations...